# Find $\gamma_n,I_n$ and $b_n$ and choose the correct options

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, functions

> Define $$\gamma_n=1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}-\log n$$
> where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\phi=\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}$. If
> $$I_n=\int_{\phi}^{\phi^2}\frac{\log^n(\log x+\gamma_n)}{\log^n(\log(\phi^3-x)+\gamma_n)+\log^n(\log x+\gamma_n)}dx$$
> And $$b_n=\lim_{k\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{k}\left(\frac{e^{2^n}-e^{-2^n}}{e^{2^n}+e^{-2^n}}\right)^\frac{1}{2^n}$$

**Choose the correct options**

$1.$ $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\gamma_n}{n}=0$

$2.$ $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}I_n^k=1$

$3.$ $e^4b_n=e^4-2I_n$

$4.$ $\log(1-b_n)+8I_n$=0

---

I beleive that to check the options, we first have to evaluate $\gamma_n,I_n$ and $b_n$.

I don't know whether there exists a closed form or approximation of $H_n-\log n$. My soul left my body when I thought of evaluating the Integral.

We can write the last expression as $$b_n=\lim_{k\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{k}(\tanh e^{2^n})^\frac{1}{2^n}$$
But I am stuck after this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The expression for $b_n$ does not depend on $n$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami how?? Can you prove it?

Comment: Prove? $n$ only appears as a index. There's no fixed $n$ in the expression. Change $n$ for $m$ (or any other letter) and the expression will have no $n$.

Comment: Oh yes I see what you are saying..but nonetheless how to evaluate it?

Comment: I don't think anyone wants you to evaluate it. Plus, since it doesn't make sense as written, I doubt that's the expression you were given.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I have written the exact question...if you wish I can attach the image also

Comment: Fair enough, but it cannot have been the intention of whoever wrote it.

Comment: Option (1) can be easily evaluated and it is correct.

Comment: The "$b_n$" have been badly written, the double usage of $n$ is poor notation. That said, if we just consider; $$b=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{x^{2^k}-x^{-2^k}}{x^{2^k}+x^{-2^k}}\right)^{2^{-k}}$$Then this [can](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4746052) be evaluated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1$ is true. We have that $$0<\frac{\gamma_n}n<\frac{H_n}n$$ Where $H_n$ is $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$. Re-write this definition as $$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac n{k(n+k)}$$So $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{H_n}n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(n+k)}=0$$Hence $1$ is true by Squeeze Theorem.

$2$ is false. We have that $$I_n=\int_\phi^{\phi^2}\frac{\log^n(\log x)}{\log^n(\log(\phi^3-x))+\log^n(\log(x))}dx=\int_\phi^{\phi^2}\frac{\log^n(\log(\phi^3-x))}{\log^n(\log(\phi^3-x))+\log^n(\log(x))}dx$$By the substitution $u=\phi^2+\phi-x=\phi^3-x$. Adding the two definitions together, we get that $$I_n=\frac{\phi^2-\phi}2=\frac12$$ And as @MartinArgerami showed, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^{-k}\ne1$. However, $I_n$ doesn't depend on $n$ (it is always $1/2$ as stated above), so $3$ and $4$ don't have to be incorrect. For them to be true, we need $b_n$ to be equal to $\frac{e^4-1}{e^4}$ (just divide $e^4$ on both sides of the equation in $3$).

Turn the product into the exponential of a sum: $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\tanh(2^n)^{\frac1{2^n}}=e^{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log(\tanh(2^n)^{\frac1{2^n}})}$$So we need to prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log(\tanh(2^n))}{2^n}=\log(e^4-1)-4$$Which is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745966/how-to-prove-that-sum-k-1-infty-frac-log-tanh2k2k-loge4-1-4)

Edit: Another way to prove $1$ is to see that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\gamma_n}n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\gamma_n\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac1n=\gamma\times0=0$$Where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni Constant. This is probably why the problem writers wrote $\gamma_n$ as such.